# uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFile task not being generated with firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.0

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

## Description

uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFile task stopped being generated after update to firebase-crashlytics-gradle >= 2.6.0.

All works fine with 2.5.2.

Is this a bug on crashlytics gradle plugin or am I missing something?

## Configurations

```
   release {
     ...
     firebaseCrashlytics {
       nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
       unstrippedNativeLibsDir file(...)
       mappingFileUploadEnabled true
     }
   }
```

## Result

```
Task 'uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease' not found in root project 'client-android'.
```

### Useful links

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports
- https://firebase.google.cn/support/release-notes/android?hl=zh-cn#crashlytics_gradle_plugin_v2-6-0